# python call a function with kwargs

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have a function:

```
def myfunc():
    kwargs = {}
    a = 1
    b = 2
    kwargs.update(a=a, b=b)
    newfunc(**kwargs)
```

and my newfunc

```
def newfunc(**kwargs):
    print a
```

Its not giving the value of a which is 1

whats wrong ?

Comment: what does it give you instead? An Error, right? That error contains an important hint: just because you've declared `kwargs` in your function signature doesn't make all elements suddenly appear in your scope.

Comment: Why would you expect `a = 1` to have any effect on `kwargs`?

Comment: `kwargs` recieves a dictionary.

Comment: First, you didn't put it to `kwargs`, second, you didn't take it from there.

Answer (score 5):

It's because you didn't put any key, value in your dictionary, you should have written that :

```
def newfunc(**kwargs):
    print kwargs["a"]

def myfunc():
    kwargs = {"a" :1, "b": 2}
    newfunc(**kwargs)
```

You can refer to this thread to understand kwargs better : [Understanding kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python)

Comment: still wrong; `print a` will have no idea where `a` should be taken from.

Comment: I did not see he also make a mistake here, it's corrected!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the error. The Error would have been a `NameError`, `a` being undefined.

There's multiple things wrong with your code:

```
def myfunc():
    kwargs = {}
    a = 1
    b = 2
```

this doesn't change the dictionary `kwargs`. This just created two new local names `a` and `b`. I guess what you wanted to have is:

```
    kwargs = {}
    kwargs["a"] = 1
    kwargs["b"] = 2
```

**EDIT:** Your update does solve the issue above this line

---

Then:

```
def newfunc(**kwargs):
    print a
```

Will give you an Error, because where should `a` come from?

Using `**kwargs` here just tells python to store all (not previously absorbed) arguments get stored in a new dictionary. What you hence want is either something like:

```
def newfunc(a,b):
    print a
```

or

```
def newfunc(**kwargs):
    print kwargs["a"]
```

---

Taking a look at your code, you seem to struggle with the concepts of how to deal with dictionaries. Maybe the question you're asking would be easier for you to answer yourself if your sat back and read a tutorial on python's `dict`

Answer (score 1):

You should add yor variables to your dictionary and print the item at position of the variable. To me it looks like your code should be written as:

```
def myfunc():
    kwargs = {'a': 1,
              'b': 2}
    newfunc(**kwargs)

def newfunc(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs['a'])

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    myfunc()
```

or your newfunc should have the arguments you want to fill with your kwargs dictionary like:

```
def myfunc():
    kwargs = {'a': 1,
              'b': 2}
    newfunc(**kwargs)

def newfunc(a, b):
    print(a)

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    myfunc()
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

First, your `kwargs` argument in `myfunc` is an empty dict, so you won't pass any parameters. If you want to pass the value of `a` and `b` to `newfunc`, you can either use

```
kwargs = {'a':1, 'b':2}
newfunc(**kwargs)
```

or

```
newfunc(a=1, b=2)
```

In both cases, you will get `'a'` and `'b'` in the kwargs dict of the `newfunc` function.

Second, you should extract your argument from the `kwargs` dict in `newfunc`. Something like `print kwargs.get('a')` should suffice.